# Can't make sticky footer. Do I have a huge bug in my code?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a sticky footer as shown in the following website: http://rafilabs.com/test-footer.html

The footer is at the bottom of the page, but if you reduce the resolution/make the browser window smaller such that the footer should cover the content, then the footer slides off screen.

I am trying to achieve the same effect but when I reduce the resolution/screen size, the footer is still at the bottom of the window, covering up some information.

I have tried to fix this using different techniques, but I can't find a solution. One problem I might have is that my sections tend not to take the height of the divs it contains, so this might lead the footer to think that those sections are in fact empty.

Picture 1:[image]
Picture 2:[image]

I have tried fixing this using overflow:hidden; and overflow:auto;, but it doesn't seem to work, and above that, it tends to muck up my existing formatting (most notable, the right border of the aside section disappears.

I'm not sure what is going on. I'm quite confused as to why stuff is not aligning as required.

I have made the code (and pictures) available, since I don't think it will scale well in JSFiddle (I still need to work on a lot of the horizontal scaling). Link: https://mega.nz/#!kAQnjJAQ!aP-JdLkrV3vfMPnczoz3JiwmmOAPEpPPQxSOiV8HZC0

Comment: Don't vandalize your post!

Answer (score 3):

As a frontend developer I too have been searching a lot on how to get footers sticky. After lots of trying, I've got some reusable code you could perhaps try:

```
/*
layout structure like this:
body 
    .page
        .site-content
        .site-footer
*/ 

html,body {
    margin:0; 
    padding:0; 
    height:100%;
}
.page {
    min-height:100%; 
    position:relative;
}
.main {
    padding:0px; 
    /* make sure footer height and main padding-bottom match */
    padding-bottom:40px;
}
.footer-block {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%; 
    left:0; 
    right:0; 
    /* make sure footer height and main padding-bottom match */
    height:40px;
}
```

In this case I mainly use divs, but I don't see why sections wouldn't work.

Comment: I believe I had something similar which was still not working. I can change everything with div, but I read that it is better to add section, header, footer etc. to increase code readability. 

I'll keep trying.

Sidenote: No idea why I'm getting downvoted. While I don't really care about up/downvotes, I would prefer people actually help, rather than downvote and leave.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `position:relative` from the `#wrapper` container. Any child element positioned absolutely inside a relatively positioned parent will stay within the boundaries of the parent.

If there is no wrapper with `position:relative` it is most likely a z-index issue. Add `z-index: 1000` to the div you want on top of the other divs. If they have a z-index set then make sure that the div you want "on top" has a higher z-index than there others.

Comment: By the .wrapper container you mean the .middle class?

I removed it now. I seemed to have gotten somewhere. The footer is now constantly under everything, which is what I want. The problem is that when there is little data on the page, the footer doesn't hug the bottom (i.e. the problem opposite what I had before).

Comment: No I am referring the to #wrapper div in the demo you provided: http://rafilabs.com/test-footer.html

Comment: Try this instead: `#wrapper{
   border: 1px solid black;
   width: 600px; 
   margin-left: auto; 
   margin-right: auto; 
   min-height: 99%;
  }`

Comment: That is not my code (that is what I am trying to achieve) I tried removing the position:relative and when the resolution is small enough, it goes over the content tab, which is not what I want. 

I feel I am quite close. The only problem now is that the footer is not sticking to the bottom of the page when there is little content.

Comment: Just downloaded your demo! Add a z-index to your footer class. Try this:  `.footer {
    display:block;
    background-color: #283F51;
    height:50px;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0 0 0 0;
    clear:both;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index:100;
}`

Comment: z-index doesn't seem like it will do much. Additionally, The code provided only works if the content does not overflow the page. If it does, the footer covers information. I have cleaned up the code a bit. If you want I can upload the updated code. 



The problem seems that relative and absolute positioning will only give me one functionality. Absolute works provided the content is smaller than the page. Fixed works provided the content is larger than the page. Both are somewhat fixed, since we can have changes in resolution. Not sure if I made myself clear enough.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82728/discussion-between-bennyticklez-and-the-malteser).